# How to ensure one child record remains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my Rails 4 application I have `users` who can have many `rates`.

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :amount, :presence => true

  ...

end
```

A rate has a `name`, an `amount`, and a boolean attribute `default`.

How can I make sure that the `user` cannot accidentally delete his last `rate`, i.e. that at least one rate always remains associated with the user and that that rate's default attribute is set to `true` if there is no other rate remaining?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a specific method like this

```
class User
  def delete_rate(rate)
    if rates.count > 1
      self.rates.delete(rate)
    else
      raise "User should have at least one rate"
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can add a validation like this :

```
class User
  validates :rates, length: { minimum: 1 }
end
```

but this last solution can introduce issues on User creation.

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like...

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :amount, :presence => true

  after_initialize :set_default, if: ->{ user.rates.count == 1 }
  after_destroy :ensure_rate_exists

 private

   def set_default
    self.default = true
   end

   def ensure_rate_exists
    raise "Cannot remove.." if user.rates.count.zero?
   end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the validation to the User, and manage the Rates as nested attributes. something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rates, dependent: :destroy 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rates, allow_destroy: true
  validates_presence_of :rates
end
```

and rates need not worry

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  after_initialize :set_default, if: ->{ user.rates.count == 1 }
  ...

private

  def set_default
   self.default = true
  end 
end
```